# How to AND result of an AND condition with another condition in .NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck in writing this query. i have these tables:

**Cuisine:**
 CuisineID
 CuisineName
 CuisineType

**Dishes:**
 DishID
DishName
CuisineID

**Facility:**
 FacilityID
 FacilityName

**RestaurantDish:**
 RestaurantDishID
 RestaurantID
 DishID

**Restaurants:**
   RestaurantID 
   Name
   City
   Location
   PhoneNo

i have to display restaurants depending upon user selection of facility or dish or cuisine. once i have a list of restaurant, i have to refine further same list by every selection of user.  i have written this stoed procedure which is not working:

```
          ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetFilterData]
@searchText NVARCHAR(MAX),
@DishIDs NVARCHAR(200) ,
@FacilitDs NVARCHAR(200) ,
@CuisineIDs NVARCHAR(200)
 AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = '';

    SET @sql = 'SELECT  RestaurantID ,
            Name ,
            City ,
            Location ,
            Country ,
            PhoneNo1 ,
            PhoneNo2 ,
            PhoneNo3 ,
            FaxNumber ,
            Timings ,
            HappyHour ,
            Menu ,
            Buffet ,
            Rating ,
            DateCreated ,
            Datemodified ,
            DateDeleted
    FROM    dbo.Restaurants AS r
    WHERE   ( RestaurantID IN (
              SELECT    rd.RestaurantID
              FROM      dbo.RestaurantDish AS rd
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Dishes1 AS d ON d.DishID = rd.DishID
              WHERE     ( d.DishName LIKE ''%' + @searchText + '%'''

    IF @DishIDs <> '' 
        BEGIN
            SET @sql =@sql + '   AND d.DishID IN ( ' + @DishIDs + ' )'

        END 
    SET @sql =@sql + ') ) )'       
    SET @sql =@sql + ' AND ( RestaurantID IN (
                 SELECT rf.RestaurantID
                 FROM   dbo.RestaurantFacility AS rf
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Facilities1 AS f ON f.FacilityID = rf.FacilityID
                 WHERE  ( f.FacilityName LIKE ''%' + @searchText + '%'''
    IF @FacilitDs <> '' 
        BEGIN
            SET @sql =@sql + ' AND f.FacilityID IN ( ' + @FacilitDs + ' )'
        END
    SET @sql =@sql + ') ) )'  
    SET @sql =@sql + '  OR ( RestaurantID IN (
                 SELECT RestaurantID
                 FROM   dbo.RestaurantDish
                 WHERE  ( DishID IN (
                          SELECT    dbo.RestaurantDish.DishID
                          FROM      dbo.Cuisine1
                          WHERE     ( CuisineName LIKE ''%' + @searchText
        + '%'')'
    IF @CuisineIDs <> '' 
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql +' AND CuisineID IN ( ' + @CuisineIDs + ' )'
        END
    SET @sql =@sql + ') ) ))'                         
    SET @sql =@sql + '  OR ( Name LIKE ''%' + @searchText + '%'')
            OR ( City LIKE ''%' + @searchText + '%'')
            OR ( Country LIKE ''%' + @searchText + '%'')
            OR ( Buffet LIKE ''%' + @searchText + '%'')
            OR ( Location LIKE ''%' + @searchText + '%'')'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;     
END
```

i dont know what to do else..
 this is my class:

```
         public class DBAccess
       {
        public DBAccess()
       {
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
        }
private SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    SqlConnection con = null;
    try
    {
        string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["food4uConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        con.Close();
        throw;
    }
    return con;
}

public List<Restaurants> GetAllRestaurents(string searchText, string dishIDs, string facilityIDs, string cuisineIDS)
{
    List<Restaurants> restaurants = null;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetFilterData", GetConnection());
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("searchText", searchText);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DishIDs", dishIDs);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FacilitDs", facilityIDs);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CuisineIDs", cuisineIDS);

        SqlDataReader dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        restaurants = new List<Restaurants>();
        while (dreader.Read())
        {
            restaurants.Add(new Restaurants()
            {
                RestaurantID = (int)dreader["RestaurantID"],
                Name = (string)dreader["Name"],
                City = (string)dreader["City"],
                Country = (string)dreader["Country"],
                Location = (string)dreader["Location"],
                PhoneNo1 = (string)dreader["PhoneNo1"],
                PhoneNo2 = (string)dreader["PhoneNo2"],
                PhoneNo3 = (string)dreader["PhoneNo3"],
                Menu = (string)dreader["Menu"],
                HappyHour = (string)dreader["HappyHour"],
                Buffet = (string)dreader["Buffet"],
                Rating = (string)dreader["Rating"],
                FaxNo = (string)dreader["FaxNumber"],
                Timings = (DateTime)dreader["Timings"],
                DateCreated = (DateTime)dreader["DateCreated"],
                DateDeleted = (DateTime)dreader["DateDeleted"],
                Datemodified = (DateTime)dreader["DateModified"]
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return restaurants;
}

public List<Facilities1> GetFacilities(int restaurentID, string facilityID)
{
    List<Facilities1> facilities = null;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetFacilities", GetConnection());
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RestaurantID", restaurentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FacilityID", facilityID);
        SqlDataReader dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        facilities = new List<Facilities1>();
        while (dreader.Read())
        {
            facilities.Add(new Facilities1()
            {
                FacilityID = (int)dreader["FacilityID"],
                FacilityName = (string)dreader["FacilityName"]
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return facilities;
}

public List<Dishes1> GetDishes(int restaurentID, string dishID)
{
    List<Dishes1> dishes = null;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetDishes", GetConnection());
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RestaurantID", restaurentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DishID", dishID);
        SqlDataReader dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dishes = new List<Dishes1>();
        while (dreader.Read())
        {
            dishes.Add(new Dishes1()
            {
                DishID = (int)dreader["DishID"],
                DishName = (string)dreader["DishName"],
                Price = (int)dreader["Price"]
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return dishes;
}

public List<Cuisine> GetCuisines(int restaurentID, string cousineID)
{
    List<Cuisine> cuisines = null;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetCuisines", GetConnection());
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RestaurantID", restaurentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CuisineID", cousineID);
        SqlDataReader dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cuisines = new List<Cuisine>();
        while (dreader.Read())
        {
            cuisines.Add(new Cuisine()
            {
                CuisineID = (int)dreader["CuisineID"],
                CuisineName = (string)dreader["CuisineName"]
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return cuisines;
}

public List<Dishes1> GetAllDishes()
{
    List<Dishes1> dishes = null;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select DishID, DishName From Dishes1", GetConnection());
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dishes = new List<Dishes1>();
        while (dreader.Read())
        {
            dishes.Add(new Dishes1()
            {
                DishID = (int)dreader["DishID"],
                DishName = (string)dreader["DishName"]
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return dishes;
}

public List<Cuisine> GetAllCuisine()
{
    List<Cuisine> cuisines = null;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select CuisineID,  CuisineName From Cuisine1", GetConnection());
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cuisines = new List<Cuisine>();
        while (dreader.Read())
        {
            cuisines.Add(new Cuisine()
            {
                CuisineID = (int)dreader["CuisineID"],
                CuisineName = (string)dreader["CuisineName"]
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return cuisines;
}

public List<Facilities1> GetAllFacilities()
{
    List<Facilities1> facilities = null;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select FacilityID, FacilityName from Facilities1", GetConnection());
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        facilities = new List<Facilities1>();
        while (dreader.Read())
        {
            facilities.Add(new Facilities1()
            {
                FacilityID = (int)dreader["FacilityID"],
                FacilityName = (string)dreader["FacilityName"]
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return facilities;
}
```

} 
/////
here is another class:

```
             public partial class Restaurant : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
public string facility = null;
public string cuis = null;
public string dish = null;
public string location = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindListView();
        BindDishesAsCheckBoxes();
    }
}

private void BindListView()
{
    string searchText = this.txtSearch.Text;
    string facilityIDs = hfFacilityID.Value == "" ? "" : hfFacilityID.Value.Remove(hfFacilityID.Value.Length - 1);
    string dishIDs = hfDishID.Value == "" ? "" : hfDishID.Value.Remove(hfDishID.Value.Length - 1);
    string cuisineIDs = hfCuisineID.Value == "" ? "" : hfCuisineID.Value.Remove(hfCuisineID.Value.Length - 1);

    try
    {
        DBAccess objDB = new DBAccess();
        listView.DataSource = objDB.GetAllRestaurents(searchText, dishIDs, facilityIDs, cuisineIDs);
        listView.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

private void BindDishesAsCheckBoxes()
{
    try
    {
        DBAccess objdb = new DBAccess();

        //dishes
        chkDishes.DataSource = objdb.GetAllDishes();
        chkDishes.DataBind();

        //cuisines
        chkCuisine.DataSource = objdb.GetAllCuisine();
        chkCuisine.DataBind();

        //facilities
        chkFacilities.DataSource = objdb.GetAllFacilities();
        chkFacilities.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

#region itemdatabound

protected void ContactsListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

    string facilityIDs = hfFacilityID.Value == "" ? "" : hfFacilityID.Value.Remove(hfFacilityID.Value.Length - 1);
    string dishIDs = hfDishID.Value == "" ? "" : hfDishID.Value.Remove(hfDishID.Value.Length - 1);
    string cuisineIDs = hfCuisineID.Value == "" ? "" : hfCuisineID.Value.Remove(hfCuisineID.Value.Length - 1);
    try
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            Label lbl1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRestaurentID");
            DBAccess objdb = new DBAccess();

            //bind  facility
            Repeater rpFacility = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptFacility");
            rpFacility.DataSource = objdb.GetFacilities(Convert.ToInt32(lbl1.Text), facilityIDs);
            rpFacility.DataBind();

            //bind  dishes
            Repeater rpDish = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptDish");
            rpDish.DataSource = objdb.GetDishes(Convert.ToInt32(lbl1.Text), dishIDs);
            rpDish.DataBind();

            //bind  dishes
            Repeater rptCuisine = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptCuisine");
            rptCuisine.DataSource = objdb.GetCuisines(Convert.ToInt32(lbl1.Text), cuisineIDs);
            rptCuisine.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //dvError.Visible = true;
        //lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

#endregion

protected void chkDishes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in chkDishes.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            string id = item.Value;
            hfDishID.Value += id + ",";
            BindListView();
        }
    }
}

protected void chkCuisine_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in chkCuisine.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            string id = item.Value;
            hfCuisineID.Value += id + ",";
            BindListView();
        }
    }
}

protected void chkFacilities_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in chkFacilities.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            string id = item.Value;
            hfFacilityID.Value += id + ",";
            BindListView();
        }
    }
}

protected void btnSeach_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindListView();
}
```

}

Comment: You marked this question with .NET tag. So, where is .NET?

Comment: This query is ripe for the [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)! Hint: think what is going to happen if `@searchText` equals |`');DROP TABLE Restaurants; --`| (with no vertical bars) Warning: please do not try it!

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: i am implementing it in .NET.

Comment: "Not working" is rather vague.  For instance, if I put this on a SQL Server system such as SQL Fiddle, it would fail because the tables are not defined.

Comment: @gh9 if user select any of facility,dishes or cuisines, list of restaurants containing them appear. if user further select anything, same list is further refined.

Comment: Why do you construct the query dynamically and execute it, instead of selecting the rows in the stored procedure?

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do u exactly mean by "tables not defined"??? couldn't get it

Comment: @justalearner . . . Your question says that something doesn't work.  That's all.  We have no idea what the problem is.  If I tried to put your code on another database, there would surely be at least the error  at the tables do not exist.  Can you provide more information about what is happening?

Comment: @flup i have tried to select the rows, but it returns all the restaurants even if any selection is made

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have used this stored procedure in my c# code but this procedure returns all the restaurants rather than the ones which fulfill user selection. got it?

Comment: @justalearner . . . I would suggest that you edit the question or ask a new one that includes the call to the stored procedure and prints out the SQL that is being generated.  If I had to guess, it is a parentheses problem in the `where` clause.

Comment: That query just makes no sense to me.  Why would you require dishname and facililty name to both match the same value.  Or search city, country, buffet, location, and CuisineName for the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing dynamic SQL which depends on the user putting the strings in correctly.  I would think the explosion may be occurring due to an error in the string creation.

To debug I would change this line:

```
 Execute sp_executesql @sql
```

to

```
 print @sql
```

this will give you the raw text of the expression.  You can copy and paste that and see what is blowing up.  Keep in mind that dynamic sql can get very messy very fast in that you are transposing an operation into the engine you are building from a string.

You must ensure your users are passing in legitimate variables I would assume of

```
' ''valA'', ''valB'', ''ValC'' '
```

As you need to mark up quotes with double quotes when passing in an array of varchar fields that are varchar fields themselves.  This presents a problem as you then have to ensure your fields getting passed in are legitimate themselves.  Some people have figured out different means to deal with this problem and I could offer a few suggestions in addition to the method of debugging your code:

Honestly if you have SQL Server 2008 or higher I would look into using the 'table type' to declare a custom type that can be a table type.  Populate that table with your arrays you are looking for and pass that in.  You can build table functions that take table types after 2008.  Functions IMHO may not always perform as well as procs but they are very readable and function alone as objects that can be linked to which make them very good for following rules of encapsulation and usability.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are dynamically constructing the `@sql`, I assume, is that you wish to provide a comma separated list of IDs as criteria for the dishes, cuisine, and facilities.

This makes the query unreadable, however. So do not do this.

Depending on your usage, use [a Table-Valued Parameter](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) for each of these criteria or [a split function](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) that will split the string for you.

A simple but readable split function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnStringSplit] (@list ntext)
         RETURNS @table TABLE (token varchar(4000) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) 
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @pos       int,
              @textpos   int,
              @chunklen  smallint,
              @chunk     nvarchar(4000),
              @leftover  nvarchar(4000),
              @token     nvarchar(4000),
              @delimiter nchar(1)

      SET @delimiter = N','
      SET @textpos = 1
      SET @leftover = ''
      WHILE @textpos <= datalength(@list) / 2
      BEGIN
         SET @chunklen = 4000 - len(@leftover)
         SET @chunk = @leftover + substring(@list, @textpos, @chunklen)
         SET @textpos = @textpos + @chunklen

         SET @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @chunk)
         WHILE @pos > 0
         BEGIN
            SET @token = left(@chunk, @pos - 1)
            INSERT @table (token) VALUES(@token)
            SET @chunk = substring(@chunk, @pos + 1, len(@chunk))
            SET @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @chunk)
         END

         SET @leftover = @chunk
      END

      INSERT @table(token) VALUES (@leftover)
      RETURN
END
```

Once you have rewritten the query, correcting it ought to be trivial.